# Speech to text using python. not printing anything also have no error

Tags: python, data-science, speech-recognition

i am doing speech to text this is a code but when i run this code. no error shown. but not printing any this.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os 
from pydub import AudioSegment
import speech_recognition as sr
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
def load_chunks(file):
    long_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)
    audio_chunks = split_on_silence(
        long_audio, min_silence_len=1800,
        silence_thresh=-17
    )
    return audio_chunks
for audio_chunk in load_chunks('F:/office work/audio1.wav'):
    audio_chunk.export("temp", format="wav")
    with sr.AudioFile("temp") as source:
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        try:
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print("Chunk : {}".format(text))
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error occured")
            print(ex)
```

Comment: why you have done it so complex just use speech_recognition library it will work just go through documentation

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above by @Bhavya Parikh, why do you need to do these much complex programming for a simple Speech to Text programs? Let me give a better code below

```
import speech_recognition as sr
#Needed Module

r = sr.Recognizer()
#Initializes r for Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("You can speak now")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print("Time Over")

#Default Mic as source, it listens

try:
    print("TEXT: "+r.recognize_google(audio));
    #Prints the Output

except:
    pass;
    #Does nothing, if error occurred(No error is showed on-scree)
```

Remember, Internet is required to run this code, as it uses Google's Recognizer.
And this code is much faster as it uses less libraries and functions.

This code should help!